# Conditional has_many in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

My app has applicants with many question_sections with many questions with many answers.

Here I am returning these for an applicant

```
@question_sections = QuestionSection.find(
  :all, :include => {:questions => :answers},
  :conditions => ['answers.application_form_id is NULL OR answers.application_form_id = ?', @application_form.id],
  :order => 'question_sections.list_index ASC, questions.list_index ASC'
)
```

What I'd like to do is return a row even if the answer row is null (ie, a left join on answer) so we can identify questions that have not been answered rather than omitting them entirely (which is what happens currently.)

I think the issue might be that the answer belongs to both the question and the applicant;

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base 

  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :application_form, :touch => true
```

So, is pseudo code I'd like 'belongs_to :application_form IF :application_form is not null' - to retain any potential associations.

While I can write all this with SQL fairly easily, I'd like to let rails handle that and fix the model.

In SQL I want to go from this

```
FROM `question_sections`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `questions` ON questions.question_section_id = question_sections.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `answers` ON answers.question_id = questions.id
WHERE ((answers.application_form_id IS NULL
        OR answers.application_form_id = 656))
```

to this

```
FROM `question_sections`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `questions` ON questions.question_section_id = question_sections.id
LEFT JOIN `answers` ON answers.question_id = questions.id AND answers.application_form_id = 656
// No WHERE
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

What I need, I think, is a lambda on the has_many association. Something like;

```
has_many :answers_and_null_answers, :whatever => lambda ( a = Answer.find(n); if a.nil? a = Answer.new; )
```

Obviously, thats just messy pseudo - but is this possible?

**EDIT #2**

Aha! first_or_create does what I want, but seems you can'd do it on :includes. I'm assuming there is something I can do to the model to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I went with was to add raw SQL to find() call. Wrote my joins manually and then edited the view to suit the different output.

Not what I would have preferred to do, but it works.